# Thread safety of std::map for read-only operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, thread-safety, stdmap

I have a std::map that I use to map values (field ID's) to a human readable string. This map is initialised once when my program starts before any other threads are started, and after that it is never modified again. Right now, I give every thread its own copy of this (rather large) map but this is obviously inefficient use of memory and it slows program startup. So I was thinking of giving each thread a pointer to the map, but that raises a thread-safety issue.

If all I'm doing is reading from the map using the following code:

```
std::string name;
//here N is the field id for which I want the human readable name
unsigned field_id = N; 
std::map<unsigned,std::string>::const_iterator map_it;

// fields_p is a const std::map<unsigned, std::string>* to the map concerned.
// multiple threads will share this.
map_it = fields_p->find(field_id);
if (map_it != fields_p->end())
{
    name = map_it->second;
}
else
{
    name = "";
}
```

Will this work or are there issues with reading a std::map from multiple threads?

Note: I'm working with visual studio 2008 currently, but I'd like this to work acros most main STL implementations.

Update: Edited code sample for const correctness.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will work from multiple threads as long as your map remains the same. The map you use is immutable de facto so any find will actually do a find in a map which does not change.

Here is a relevant link: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/thread_safety.html

> The SGI implementation of STL is
>   thread-safe only in the sense that
>   simultaneous accesses to distinct
>   containers are safe, and simultaneous
>   read accesses to to shared containers
>   are safe. If multiple threads access a
>   single container, and at least one
>   thread may potentially write, then the
>   user is responsible for ensuring
>   mutual exclusion between the threads
>   during the container accesses.

You fall into he "simultaneous read accesses to shared containers" category.

Note: this is true for the SGI implementation. You need to check if you use another implementation. Of the two implementations which seem widely used as an alternative, STLPort has built-in thread safety as I know. I don't know about the Apache implementation though.

Comment: Note: The answer is limited to the SGI STL implemenation. The OP did not mention which one is used.

Comment: I use the implementation that comes with visual studio 2008, but I was looking for an answer that covers the std::map in general, or at least across most implementations if this is at all possible.

Comment: Check the STL/CRL documentation(for VS20008): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385954.aspx. In my opinion, there is no reason why this would be untrue for the VS2008 implementation: it uses balanced binary trees as well as support for maps. I am sure they must have some sort of comment of thread safety in the documentation though

Comment: I'm not convinced. Just because nobody's modifying the map doesn't necessarily make it thread-safe. We don't know the details of the object's internals. There could be things going on under the hood such as caching that we don't know about. (I once wrote a hash table that cached the most recently-returned key-value pair)

Answer (score 9):

It should be fine.
You can use `const` references to it if you want to document/enforce read-only behaviour.

Note that correctness isn't guaranteed (in principle the map could choose to rebalance itself on a call to `find`), even if you do use const methods only (a really perverse implementation could declare the tree mutable).  However, this seems pretty unlikely in practise.

Comment: I would consider an implementation with mutable non thread safe internals buggy.

Comment: I updated my code slightly to use a const reference to the map and an const_iterator

Comment: drhirsch, a non-threadsafe implementation could still be standards compliant, but it would certainly be poor-quality.

Comment: @Useless: Not necessarily. Splay trees update the tree during lookup, which makes it faster to look up recently accessed elements.

Comment: Good point, although ideally such a map wouldn't provide const accessors and then make it's tree mutable.  Also: way to resurrect an old topic!  :-)

Comment: It seems to me that if the class is documented as not thread-safe (more specifically: *not* documented to be thread-safe), then it's free to implement its internals in a non-thread-safe way.

Comment: You're absolutely correct in general, which is why I said correctness isn't guaranteed. However, none of the standard library implementations I've looked at have `mutable` implementation details being mutated via const accessors/iterators. There's no reason to use them with a red-black tree. I'm certainly not aware of any `std::map` implemented using a splay tree.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.

See related post with same question about std::set:

[Is the C++ std::set thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362110/is-the-c-stl-stdset-thread-safe/1362405#1362405)

Answer (score 0):

For MS STL implementation

[Thread Safety in the C++ Standard Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/thread-safety-in-the-cpp-standard-library?view=vs-2019)

> The following thread safety rules apply to all classes in the C++ Standard Library—this includes shared_ptr, as described below. Stronger guarantees are sometimes provided—for example, the standard iostream objects, as described below, and types specifically intended for multithreading, like those in .
>
> An object is thread-safe for reading from multiple threads. For example, given an object A, it is safe to read A from thread 1 and from thread 2 simultaneously.