# Are find and read operations on std::map threadsafe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, search, dictionary, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thread safety of std::map for read-only operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846186/thread-safety-of-stdmap-for-read-only-operations)

Having `std::map a` can we do `a.find(...)->second` in multiple threads at the same time on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As long as none of your threads do a write

i.e. Construct the data structure in memory

Use as many threads to find/read as you require.

If the leaf needs altering put a mutex there.

Comment: Better still, if your OS supports it, use a read-write lock instead of just a mutex. Multiple readers, single writer, beautiful.