# Using InterlockedIncrement to increment STL map's value field. Is it threadsafe?

Tags: multithreading, dictionary, stl, thread-safety, interlocked-increment

I have a map defined like this.

```
typedef std::map< tstring, unsigned int >  ErrorToCount_T;
ErrorToCount_T m_ErrorToSuppress;
```

I am using like it like this.

```
ErrorToCount_T::iterator itr = m_ErrorToSuppress.find( val );
if( itr != m_ErrorToSuppress.end())
{
    if( (itr->second) % m_LogFreq == 0)
        //Do something
    else
        //Do something else
    InterlockedIncrement( &itr->second);
}
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198332/are-find-and-read-operations-on-stdmap-threadsafe) and I understand that find is thread-safe. But I was thinking that InterlockedIncrement( &itr->second) will be threadsafe too? Is the above code thread safe.
There are absolutely no inserts in this map in multithreaded environment.

Comment: No, reading a variable in one thread and modifying it in another is never thread-safe.  You need a true lock here, like a mutex.

Comment: I hope you meant there are absolutely no removes as well as inserts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two threads execute the code with the same key (i.e. `val`), then the expressions marked with `(1)` and `(2)` in the following listing might be executed at the same time:

```
if( (itr->second) % m_LogFreq == 0) // (1)
    //Do something
else
    //Do something else
InterlockedIncrement( &itr->second); // (2)
```

In expression `(1)` the memory location `itr->second` is read, and in expression `(2)` it is written. That is called a *data race*, and the C++11 standard states, that the behaviour of the program is undefined if it contains *data races*.

As long as your compiler vendor doesn't give you additional guarantees about the memory model, you have to use operations that don't cause *data races*. Using C++11, it might look as follows:

```
using ErrorToCount = std::map<tstring, std::atomic<unsigned int>>;
ErrorToCount errorToSuppress;

ErrorToCount::iterator itr = errorToSuppress.find( val );
if( itr != errorToSuppress.end()) {
    if (itr->second.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst) % m_LogFreq == 0)
        //Do something
    else
        //Do something else
    itr->second.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}
```