# stl map find thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, dictionary, thread-safety

Is find call on stl map thread safe?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362110/is-the-c-stl-stdset-thread-safe

Comment: Thread-safe with respect to what?  Are all threads only calling `find()` or other `const` methods?  Is the map being updated by another thread?

Comment: Lets assume all threads are only calling `find()`. Thread safe?

Answer (score 15):

No, the C++ spec makes no guarantees on thread safety in the spec for operations on any STL containers. If thread safety is important, the you should provide your own locking.

That being said, different implementations seem to offer different guarantees. Most seem to allow multiple concurrent readers, for example, as long as no writing is being performed concurrently. If you don't care about portability, you can research the documentation for your implementation. For example from [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/thread_safety.html) for SGI STL:

> The SGI implementation of STL is
>   thread-safe only in the sense that
>   simultaneous accesses to distinct
>   containers are safe, and simultaneous
>   read accesses to to shared containers
>   are safe. If multiple threads access a
>   single container, and at least one
>   thread may potentially write, then the
>   user is responsible for ensuring
>   mutual exclusion between the threads
>   during the container accesses.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362110/is-the-c-stl-stdset-thread-safe/1362405#1362405), a similar guarantee seems to be made by Dinkumware (they make Microsoft's STL implementation).

> Multiple threads can safely read the
>   same container object. (There are
>   nunprotected mutable subobjects within
>   a container object.)
>
> Two threads can safely manipulate
>   different container objects of the
>   same type. (There are no unprotected
>   shared static objects within a
>   container type.)
>
> You must protect against simultaneous
>   access to a container object if at
>   least one thread is modifying the
>   object. (The obvious synchronization
>   primitives, such as those in the
>   Dinkum Threads Library, will not be
>   subverted by the container object.)

Comment: However, most implementations provide some guarantees, such that multiple simultaneous *readers* requires no locking.  As such, multiple threads may use `std::map<>::find()` safely.

Comment: @Andre, that appears to be what most implementation offer

Comment: I swear I just had a thread safety issue today when multiple threads (in an openMP parallel for loop - VisualStudio 2010) were /reading/ an STL container : my threads were doing a std::map.find() in parallel on the same data. In debug mode, it even seems to deadlock, and in release, it causes problems to my app that do not arise when removing the parallel for loop.

Answer (score 5):

No: when another thread is updating the map concurrently with your `find`, behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find the answer to the question.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/stl__map_8h-source.html

you can see stl map souce.

---

search `find()`. It is found in 497 line, 524 line. Code is written as `_M_t.find(__x);`

---

Then search `_M_t`.

It is found in 124 line.
It is written as `_Rep_type _M_t;`

---

If property `_M_t` is created per thread, It could be thread safe.
But I don't think so.
If 2 thread use `find` concurrently, they would use `_M_t` concurrently.
`_Rep_type` is connected to `_Rb_tree`.

You can see `_Rb_tree` in below source.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/stl__tree_8h-source.html

`find()` do tree travel(see below code).
unwilled change in `__x` and `__y` would occur.

```
01307   template<typename _Key, typename _Val, typename _KeyOfValue,
01308            typename _Compare, typename _Alloc>
01309     typename _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator
01310     _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::
01311     find(const _Key& __k)
01312     {
01313       _Link_type __x = _M_begin(); // Current node.
01314       _Link_type __y = _M_end(); // Last node which is not less than __k.
01315 
01316       while (__x != 0)
01317     if (!_M_impl._M_key_compare(_S_key(__x), __k))
01318       __y = __x, __x = _S_left(__x);
01319     else
01320       __x = _S_right(__x);
01321 
01322       iterator __j = iterator(__y);
01323       return (__j == end()
01324           || _M_impl._M_key_compare(__k,
01325                     _S_key(__j._M_node))) ? end() : __j;
01326     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the STL shipped with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 seems to have some locks on operations that modify the map (and i assume it is the same for set). It is rather annoying, as i'm building more maps in multiple threads and it is killing my performance.