# unordered_map find() and operator []

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, g++, unordered-map

I have a global var std::unordered_map < std::string,int > themap .

the thread1 do the following :

```
Time1 : 
string s = "user1" ; 
themap[s] = 100 ;

Time2 :
string s = "user2" ;
themap[s] = 101 ;
```

the thread2 do the following :

```
Time2:
string s = "user1" ;
auto got = themap.find( s ) ;
```

Time1 happened before Time2 , suppose that in thread2 , got != themap.end() will be correct and got->second = 100 !!!  What bother me is that , if in the very moment Time2 , thread1 is doing themap["user2"] = 101 , which will modify themap's memory structure , thread2 themap.find doing find at the exact same time thread1 modify themap's memory contents , if without lock , still I get 
got != themap.end() ?  and got->second = 100  ?

themap["user2"] = 101 and  got = themap.find( s )
doing at the exact same time will cause  got->second not to 100   ?

Comment: If there's no synchronization between these two threads, then you have a race condition and your program exhibits undefined behavior. Which means it can legally produce any outcome whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that [unordered_map thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685486/unordered-map-thread-safety) holds for one thread writing, and multiple threads reading.

Also in your example in Time 1 you are modifying "user1" , which is then searched in thread 2 at Time 2. The fact that you set "user2" in thread 1 at Time 2 is orthogonal.

About the internal memory being modified, that is not a problem because the iterators used by find initiated while you insert a new value [will not be invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules).

Therefore in your test case there is no race condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the `unorderd_map` to change its internal structure, by forcing it to do so beforehand. Use `reserve`, and set `max_load_factor` to, or close to `1.0f`.

Comment: Thanks , but themap contents will increase to an number can not be decided beforehand ,  thanks for kindly advice !!

Comment: @barfatchen You are welcame. You can check the load_factor every time you insert. If it is approaching max_load_factor, reserve eg. 50% more, and tell the other threads.
Other solutions: Use just std::map instead, it is not considerably slower (just a bit). Alternatively you can define your own hash function that meets your criteria.