# Is the find() of unordered_map safe when operating on a unordered_map through multiple threads

Tags: c++, linux

```
uint16_t GetLevel(const string& tag)
{
    static auto *tagMap = new std::unordered_map<std::string, int>();
    static shared_timed_mutex* mtx = new shared_timed_mutex;
    std::decay<decltype(*tagMap)>::type::iterator it;
    {
        //ReadLock lock(*mtx);
        it = tagMap->find(tag);
    }
    if (it == tagMap->end()) { // new tag
        InsertLock lock(*mtx);
        it = tagMap->find(tag); // secured for two thread went across above condition
        if (it == tagMap->end()) {
            auto result = tagMap->insert({ tag, 1 });
            if (!result.second) {
                return 0;
            }
            it = result.first;
        }
    }
    return it->second;
}
```

If tagMap->find(tag) is not locked with readLock before, when tagMap performs tagMap->insert(...) in other thread, is tagMap->find(tag) safe?

Comment: You definitely get a data race when one thread does an `insert` while another thread does a `find` on the same object without mutual exclusion.

Comment: Notably relevant answer from the dupe: [A: unordered_map thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686047) explicitly mentions "using an earlier-retrieved iterator" which applies even if you uncomment `ReadLock lock(*mtx);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe. Whenever one thread does `it = tagMap->find(tag);` and another `tagMap->insert({ tag, 1 });` your iterator might be invalidated, and then using it is undefined behaviour.

[See Iterator invalidation section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Note that even uncommenting your lock for `find` operation doesn't solve this problem. You need to give an exclusive access to your whole find + modify routine.